# issue with default Application launcher

Tags: launcher

i am not able to launch any application at all.tryting to opn document viewer,system monitor,infact netwok and general settings as well not opening at all.i have tried with following trouble shooting but no luck kindly suggest.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Executed sucessfully without any error

Original CODE:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: language-selector-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-drivers-common but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-manager but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: apport-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gnome-software-plugin-snap but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: hplip but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ubuntu-software but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I have restored list of repositories and purged AppStream with

```
sudo apt-get purge appstream
```

Then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop network-manager-gnome software-properties-gtk evince indicator-bluetooth` ended with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop network-manager-gnome software-properties-gtk evince indicator-bluetooth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
indicator-bluetooth is already the newest version (0.0.6+17.10.20170605-0ubuntu3).
indicator-bluetooth set to manually installed.
evince is already the newest version (3.28.4-0ubuntu1.2).
network-manager-gnome is already the newest version (1.8.10-2ubuntu2).
network-manager-gnome set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 software-properties-gtk : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.24.32.11) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: software-properties-common but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ubuntu-drivers-common (>= 1:0.2.75) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: language-selector-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-drivers-common but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: update-manager but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: apport-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: hplip but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

checking repository :

```
$ grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/diesch-ubuntu-testing-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

update cmd output :

```
  $  sudo apt-get update
    Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
    Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
    Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
    Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
    Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed InRelease [242 kB]
    Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
    Fetched 494 kB in 3s (160 kB/s)    
    Reading package lists... Done
```

output of `$ apt-cache policy gnome-control-center`

```
$ apt-cache policy gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.5
  Version table:
     1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Package
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinutils3v5 coinor-libosi1v5 docbook-xml git-man javascript-common
  libcairo1.10-cil liberror-perl libglib3.0-cil libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libjs-xmlextras liblinear3 liblmdb0 libmono-2.0-1 libmono-2.0-dev
  libmono-accessibility4.0-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil libmono-cil-dev libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil
  libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil libmono-csharp4.0c-cil libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil
  libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libmono-db2-1.0-cil libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil libmono-http4.0-cil libmono-ldap4.0-cil
  libmono-management4.0-cil libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil libmono-messaging4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil
  libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil libmono-oracle4.0-cil libmono-parallel4.0-cil libmono-peapi4.0a-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil
  libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil libmono-relaxng4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-simd4.0-cil libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil
  libmono-sqlite4.0-cil libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil
  libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil libmono-system-data4.0-cil
  libmono-system-deployment4.0-cil libmono-system-design4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil
  libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil
  libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil
  libmono-system-json4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil libmono-system-management4.0-cil
  libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil
  libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil libmono-system-net4.0-cil libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil
  libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil
  libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil
  libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil
  libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil libmono-system-web-mobile4.0-cil libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-regularexpressions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil
  libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web4.0-cil libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil
  libmono-system-windows4.0-cil libmono-system-workflow-activities4.0-cil libmono-system-workflow-componentmodel4.0-cil
  libmono-system-workflow-runtime4.0-cil libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil
  libmono-tasklets4.0-cil libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil
  libmonosgen-2.0-1 libmonosgen-2.0-dev libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-core2.6.3-cil libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil libnunit-util2.6.3-cil libpango3.0-cil libqt5qml5 librarian0
  libzeroc-ice3.7 linux-headers-4.18.0-21 linux-headers-4.18.0-21-generic linux-headers-4.18.0-25 linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic
  linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-21-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-25-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-21-generic linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-25-generic mono-4.0-service mono-csharp-shell mono-devel mono-mcs
  mono-xbuild mono-xsp4 mono-xsp4-base monodoc-base monodoc-http monodoc-manual ocl-icd-libopencl1 rarian-compat sgml-data xml-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aptitude-common libcwidget3v5
Suggested packages:
  aptitude-doc-en | aptitude-doc apt-xapian-index debtags tasksel libcwidget-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common libcwidget3v5
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,569 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 aptitude-common all 0.8.10-6ubuntu1 [1,014 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libcwidget3v5 amd64 0.5.17-7 [286 kB]                                               
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 aptitude amd64 0.8.10-6ubuntu1 [1,269 kB]                                           
Fetched 2,569 kB in 16s (162 kB/s)                                                                                                           
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude-common.
(Reading database ... 251563 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude-common_0.8.10-6ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude-common (0.8.10-6ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcwidget3v5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcwidget3v5_0.5.17-7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcwidget3v5:amd64 (0.5.17-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude.
Preparing to unpack .../aptitude_0.8.10-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking aptitude (0.8.10-6ubuntu1) ...
Setting up aptitude-common (0.8.10-6ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcwidget3v5:amd64 (0.5.17-7) ...
Setting up aptitude (0.8.10-6ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/aptitude-curses to provide /usr/bin/aptitude (aptitude) in auto mode
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
```

APTITUDE UBUNTU DESKTOP  1:

```
$ sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apport{a} apport-gtk{a} appstream{a} apt-config-icons{a} aptdaemon{a} apturl{a} apturl-common{a} brltty{a} cups-bsd{a} eog{a} fwupd{a} 
  gdb{a} gnome-control-center{a} gnome-mahjongg{a} gnome-screenshot{a} gnome-session-canberra{a} gnome-software{a} 
  gnome-software-plugin-snap{a} gstreamer1.0-packagekit{a} hplip{ab} inputattach{a} language-selector-common{a} 
  language-selector-gnome{a} libapt-inst2.0{a} libapt-pkg-perl{ab} libbabeltrace1{a} libc6-dbg{ab} libclone-perl{ab} 
  liblist-moreutils-perl{ab} libnss-myhostname{a} libperlio-gzip-perl{ab} libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer{ab} libreoffice-calc{ab} 
  libreoffice-draw{ab} libreoffice-gnome{ab} libreoffice-gtk3{ab} libreoffice-impress{ab} libreoffice-math{ab} libreoffice-ogltrans{ab} 
  libsane-hpaio{a} libyaml-libyaml-perl{ab} lintian{a} nautilus-share{a} packagekit{a} packagekit-tools{a} patchutils{a} 
  printer-driver-hpcups{a} printer-driver-min12xxw{a} printer-driver-postscript-hp{a} printer-driver-pxljr{a} 
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth{a} python3-apport{a} python3-apt{ab} python3-aptdaemon{a} python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets{a} 
  python3-dateutil{a} python3-distupgrade{a} python3-software-properties{a} python3-systemd{ab} python3-update-manager{a} simple-scan{a} 
  software-properties-common{a} software-properties-gtk{a} ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-drivers-common{a} ubuntu-release-upgrader-core{a} 
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk{a} ubuntu-software{a} ubuntu-system-service{a} unattended-upgrades{a} update-manager{a} 
  update-manager-core{a} update-notifier{a} update-notifier-common{a} vino{a} x11-apps{a} xinit{a} xorg{a} xserver-xorg{a} 
  xserver-xorg-core{ab} xserver-xorg-legacy{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  coinor-libcbc3{u} coinor-libcgl1{u} coinor-libclp1{u} coinor-libcoinutils3v5{u} coinor-libosi1v5{u} docbook-xml{u} git-man{u} 
  javascript-common{u} libcairo1.10-cil{u} liberror-perl{u} libglib3.0-cil{u} libhwloc-plugins{u} libhwloc5{u} libjs-xmlextras{u} 
  liblinear3{u} liblmdb0{u} libmono-2.0-1{u} libmono-2.0-dev{u} libmono-accessibility4.0-cil{u} libmono-cecil-private-cil{u} 
  libmono-cil-dev{u} libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil{u} libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil{u} libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil{u} 
  libmono-csharp4.0c-cil{u} libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil{u} libmono-data-tds4.0-cil{u} libmono-db2-1.0-cil{u} 
  libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil{u} libmono-http4.0-cil{u} libmono-ldap4.0-cil{u} libmono-management4.0-cil{u} 
  libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil{u} libmono-messaging4.0-cil{u} libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil{u} 
  libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil{u} libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil{u} 
  libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil{u} libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil{u} libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil{u} 
  libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil{u} libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil{u} libmono-oracle4.0-cil{u} libmono-parallel4.0-cil{u} 
  libmono-peapi4.0a-cil{u} libmono-posix4.0-cil{u} libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil{u} libmono-relaxng4.0-cil{u} libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil{u}  



 libmono-simd4.0-cil{u} libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil{u} libmono-sqlite4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-data4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-deployment4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-design4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-json4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-management4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-net4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil{u} libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil{u} libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil{u} libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil{u} libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil{u} libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil{u} libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil{u} libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil{u} libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil{u} 
      libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil{u} libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil{u}
```

result of purge autoremove :

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.18.0-21* linux-headers-4.18.0-21-generic* linux-headers-4.18.0-25* linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic*
  linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic* linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic* linux-modules-4.18.0-21-generic* linux-modules-4.18.0-25-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 8 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 316 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 238865 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.18.0-21-generic (4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.18.0-21 (4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.18.0-25-generic (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.18.0-25 (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic (4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-modules-4.18.0-21-generic (4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1) ...
Removing linux-modules-4.18.0-25-generic (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
(Reading database ... 179441 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic (4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-4.18.0-21-generic (4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-modules-4.18.0-25-generic (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
```

Comment: hi norbert please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)